# Matlab: Export mesh plot with 6 million elements to pdf

Tags: matlab, pdf, matlab-figure, mesh

I am trying to export a figure in Matlab to pdf. The figure consists of 6 subplots and each of these subplots is a mesh plot. One of the mesh plots is based on 6 million data points while another one is based on 4 million data points. The rest are based on less points.

I export the figure using Matlab's print command. The issue I have is that this process takes along time. Probably more than half an hour.

I have also tried to use the export_fig function but this does not work at all.

Is there any more efficient way to export this figure to pdf in Matlab?

Comment: Do you insist on having vector graphic output? I wouldn't be surprised if a raster format such as a png would be much faster. Note that such a huge vectorized data set might give indigestion to your pdf viewer and/or printer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to include it in a LaTex document and pdf/svg gives a much higher quality plot. However, there are only a few plots with this many elements so I could perhaps try to see how the png looks. It migth be the only feasible option.

Comment: As @AndrasDeak said, use a PNG. MATLAB stores meshes in a *very* inefficient way in vector graphics formats and it's only going to cause you headaches down the road. The resulting PDF file from this is also huge. You can increase the resolution of the PNG to be suitable for use in your document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to compromise with vector graphics quality, you could try to print to pdf format with '-opengl' renderer option. It will give pdf with rasterize output. You can increase the resolution for better quality output.

Try this,

```
% Print current figure to foo.pdf with opengl renderer and 300 resolution
print('foo', '-dpdf', '-opengl', '-r300')
```